# A spawner that spawns in a certain area

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have been working on a game and my brain is dead I need help does anyone have a good base script to spawn objects at a random interval something like a metor game where metor's are spawned at top like does airplane shooting dodger. (The meaning of insanity is doing something over and over again and expecting a different outcome.)

Comment: Create an empty GameObject, maybe place it at the point, where you're object are supposed to appear. Make a `public GameObject` variable (or even better `[SerializeField] private GameObject`) and assign a refference to a prefab. Make a float variable, set it to the time inbetween appearances and decrease it by 'Time.deltaTime' in the `Update` method and instantiate you object like so: `Instantiate(myPrefab, transform.position + Random.insideUnitSphere * 5, Quaternion.identity);`. This should be enough as a starting point, i hope. And really try to formulate your questions better.

Comment: And you should definitely find something online. Just asking for code on StackOverflow will probably not get you very far. Besides i think this actually violating the community guidelines...

Comment: I am new to programming sorry and I dident even get the code to work with clear steps I am hopeless sorry to bother you but can you check if there are any errors

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RainSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
      public GameObject myPrefab;
    
     public float timeBetweenSpawn;

   void update(){
     timeBetweenSpawn = 5 - Time.deltaTime; 
     Instantiate(myPrefab, transform.position + Random.insideUnitSphere * 5, Quaternion.identity);
   }

}

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RainSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
      public GameObject myPrefab;
    
     public float timeBetweenSpawn;

   void update(){
     timeBetweenSpawn = 5 - Time.deltaTime; 
     Instantiate(myPrefab, transform.position + Random.insideUnitSphere * 5, Quaternion.identity);
   }

}

Answer (score 0):

The code still doesn't work are there any errors?

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RainSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject myPrefab;

```
 public float timeBetweenSpawn;
```

void update(){
timeBetweenSpawn = 5 - Time.deltaTime;
Instantiate(myPrefab, transform.position + Random.insideUnitSphere * 5, Quaternion.identity);
}

}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can try to write a plane script, this script controls the movement of the plane, when you press the left mouse button to shoot a bullet, there will be a sound effect when the bullet is fired. The parameter of the GameObject of the bullet is implemented in the preset, because there is no bullet in the scene at the beginning, and the player presses the left mouse button to have an instance of the bullet. The Update and FixedUpdate functions are used here. Several update functions distinguish Update. The number of frames called each frame is related to the current platform and is affected by device performance; FixedUpdate is called at fixed time intervals; LateUpdate is called every frame, but it is called after Update is executed; in general, it is called The frequency and sequence are different. Mathf.Clamp function, the parameter is a floating point number, it is a static function that limits the value, Mathf.Clamp (value min max) value is between min and max, it returns value, if the value is too small, it returns min, and if the value is too large, it returns max . This is used to limit the movement range of the aircraft. I am also looking for information and hope it can help you.